# I'm trying to make the uniq command from linux using C coding

Tags: c, arrays, function, file, uniq

I am trying to make the uniq command using C coding, which will remove and duplicate lines as part of a homework assignment. I am 1 year into java and literally jsut started C programming. it's overwhelming. I decided the basic thing to do was make a program that takes in a file, and prints out its contents. Next i decided to make the program tell how many lines there are. The problem i have now is to make each line display its respective line. in my code, each line will display its line and the one before this. After this, i need to figure out how to make my program scan each line for duplicated and delete them. Any help would do, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void process_file(FILE* f);
char str [1000];
char c;
int r=0;
int line;
char temp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    process_file(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

void process_file(FILE* f){
    FILE *fp = fopen(f,"r");
    if ( fp == NULL){
        printf("Error: No such file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){

        str[r] = c;
        r++;
        if (c =='\n'){
            line++;
            printf("new line %d\n", line);
            printf("%s\n", str);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: `(c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF` is nonsense with `char c`. `fgetc` returns an `int` on purpose.

Comment: Easy solution: after detecting a new line compare the current line to all previously stored lines. If line exists, do not store it. Perfomance solution: store and compare not lines but their hashes.

Comment: `uniq` requires the file to be sorted, so it only needs to compare with the preceding line, not all previous lines.

Comment: You need to add null terminators to your strings when you get to the end of the line. You could also use `fgets()` to read a whole line at a time.

Comment: You're not starting a new string after you read a line, you're just appending to the same string as all the previous lines. So `printf("%s\n", str);` will print the entire file read so far. And if the file is more than 1000 characters you'll overflow the buffer.

Comment: The `uniq` command can also take no command-line arguments and read from `stdin`.

Comment: yes i  realize that i'm just appending characters into the array. how do you think i should go about making each line a seperate string?

Comment: You started off pretty good: Separate your problem into smaller subproblems. Good ones: How to read a line, Comparing Lines, Writing a line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the temporary file in order to save unique line in it and check the new read line to its line. Eventually, you could read and print that.

when you read the new line from input file, check if it exists in temporary file, if so, go to next new line. If not, add it to temporary file as a unique line and go to the next line.

Notes:
Be sure that maximum number of line characters do not exceed from str array length.
Using the array variables to maintain all unique lines is not a good idea, when the input file is large and it has a lot of unique lines. If you know the input file size is small, you can handle that with the two demential array, instead of file.

If you decide to use the temporary file, while checking the repetitive lines, Go At The First Of File Every Time, read line by line, and search if the new line does exist or not.

Use fgets function to read the line completely, instead of reading char by char.